# Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am working on Appium for an android device. So here I am trying to select a radio button -say OneWay in Spice Jet for booking a flight and using the xpath, but I am getting issue's as follows:

1. `"org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver"`
2. `"TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. "`

Comment: The first issue is resolved and it is due to synchronization problem but the issue 2 as it was fixed in the latest appium.

Comment: The bug is still open. Are you sure it's been addressed?

Comment: Ok but in my case this issue is not replicating now

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the Selenium docs

> A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:
>
> The element has been deleted entirely.
>
> The element is no longer attached to the DOM

In you case, please check if the element you're trying to find is available or not available on DOM.

The second issue is a current issue in Appium- see [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5454)!